# Mapping function with datetime from a dictionary to change a given output

Tags: python, pandas

***Context:*** I'd like to use a dictionary to map datetime to change the extracted years according to the pair of key:values on a given dictionary. Here's a quick example:

Let's say we have a dataframe with datetime:

```
       Week
1   2019-06-10
2   2019-06-17
3   2019-06-24
4   2019-07-01
```

And we extract the year from this as such:

```
test['year'] = test['Week'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

Resulting in this:

```
       Weelk    year
1   2019-06-10  2019
2   2019-06-17  2019
3   2019-06-24  2019
4   2019-07-01  2019
```

***Desired Output:*** How could I make it so that when passing this dictionary:

```
date_mapping = {
    '2019-12-30':'2020',
    '2021-01-04':'2021',
    '2022-01-03':'2022'
}
```

I can "grab" the `keys` of the dictionary and if the datetime is `2019-12-30`, for example, the `year` column would be changed to 2020 instead of 2019?

The output after mapping this dictionary would look like this:

```
       Week     year
1   2019-06-10  2019
2   2019-06-17  2019
3   2019-06-24  2019
4   2019-07-01  2019
...
30  2019-12-30  2020
```

***Tested implementations:***

I was trying to use the `map` function, but I keep getting NaN for the `year` column

```
test['year'] = test['Week'].map(date_mapping,test['year'])

       Week     year
1   2019-06-10  NaN
2   2019-06-17  NaN
3   2019-06-24  NaN
4   2019-07-01  NaN
```

Do I need to convert the datestrings to dt or anything like that? Not quite sure where to start on that

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.replace`

```
test.Week = pd.to_datetime(test.Week)

test.year = test.Week.replace({
    '2019-12-30':'2020',
    '2021-01-04':'2021',
    '2022-01-03':'2022'
}).dt.year
```